# Scaling different amounts on each axis in Keynote

Tags: keynote

In Keynote it's easy to build an animation wherein you scale or rotate an item uniformly on horizontal and vertical. But is there a way to scale an object only on the vertical axis?

This is on the latest version of Keynote (6.5.3).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you can do it through the usual Actions applied to the object, but you should be able to get what you want using **Magic Move**.

Get your slide the way you want it, then duplicate it.

In the second copy, scale the object to the new stretched out size (deselect **Constrain proportions** to stretch the vertical axis).

Then click back on your first slide and in the **Animate** tab, choose **Magic Move**.

When you play your slide and go to the next, it should scale your object to its new vertically stretched size.

Comment: Aw jeeze, I wish I'd known about that about three hours ago. :) I'll try that out!

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, and what the OP wants may not even pertain to this, but there's a simpler trick I use to turn an object around. This assumes the object can be reversed (i.e., a graphic, text box, or shape; a table can't do this):

1. Apply a "Flip" to the object's Build Out property.
2. Create a reverse version of what you want to flip by...
3. Change the Build Out to none
4. Change the Build In to "Flip"
5. Adjust the Build In of the reverse to apply WITH the previous build (the Build Out)
6. Make sure the Build Out of the original object and the Build In of the reverse have the same timing or things will get kind of weird.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't pertain to the specific question I was asking - I wanted to be able to move and scale an object as part of a complex animation between two related charts, specifically a box on one chart moving and resizing to match the box on another chart to indicate they were one and the same.